# Isomorphism between elliptic curves over $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb F_5$

Tags: elliptic-curves

Given are the Elliptic curves $E_1 : y^2 = x^3+x$ and $E_2 = y^2 = x^3+3x$. Are these isomorphic over

a) $\mathbb Q$?

b) $\mathbb F_5$?

I see they are isomorphic over $\mathbb C$, as they have the same $j$-invariant. I suppose they aren't isomorphic, but how to prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** They are isomorphic over $K$ if and only there exists a $u\in K^{\times}$ such that $u^4=3$, see [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=V5oACAAAQBAJ&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=Given+are+the+Elliptic+curves+E1:y2%3Dx3%2Bx+and+E2%3Dy2%3Dx3%2B3x.+Are+these+isomorphic+over++Q&source=bl&ots=kExrNi_E4C&sig=ACfU3U3wCw8OcGQxacFSkwXvJBlnMzU6TA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBzNbMyubiAhU76KYKHTW2C44Q6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=Given%20are%20the%20Elliptic%20curves%20E1%3Ay2%3Dx3%2Bx%20and%20E2%3Dy2%3Dx3%2B3x.%20Are%20these%20isomorphic%20over%20%20Q&f=false).

Actually, for $y^2=x^3+x$ we have $E(\Bbb F_5)\cong C_2\times C_2$, and for $y^2=x^3+3x$ we have $E(\Bbb F_5)\cong C_{10}$.